# Any way to integrate or run protractor tests from VSTS and bring the result back in VSTS?

Tags: protractor, azure-devops

Right now I'm creating a build with Ubuntu shell commands in VSTS to copy the code from VSTS to an external AWS static server which has already installed npm and protractor. Then the execution is triggered from VSTS build using same ubuntu shell commands and the final HTML reports are being saved in that server itself.

Any other way to bring back the results folder into VSTS? or to create any dashboard to show that HTML reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the protractor-trx-reporter package to create a trx report and then after your test is finished, pull the results back into a folder in Azure Devops*(VSTS). Use the "publish test results" task to make the results viewable.

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-trx-reporter)